# How do I know which Windows API version is called?

Tags: windows, winapi, x86, reverse-engineering

if I were to set several breakpoints how do I know whether the A or W version has been called by the program without bruteforce?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense, sorry. Where are you setting the breakpoints? A or W version of what?

Comment: @JonathanPotter For example if the program uses LoadLibraryA or LoadLibraryW

Answer (score 2):

Just set breakpoints on both versions.

Any program can use both ANSI and Wide versions simultaneously, by explicitly specifying which one.

Comment: The `A` is short for ANSI, not ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

I create a simple example:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("test"), TEXT("test"), 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Set a breakpoint at `MessageBox`, then step into `MessageBox` in Disassembly:

If you use `Multi-Byte Character Set`, you can see:

[image]

And when you use  `Unicode Character Set`:

[image]

You can easily see which function it calls through disassembly.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a breakpoint outside of a given function call before it is entered, then when the breakpoint is reached you can step into the call to see which function is actually jumped to.

If you put a breakpoint inside both functions, you will easily see which one is called.